# Height and width transition origin point

Tags: html, css

Does it possible to set the start location of a transition ?

i.e -

Suppose I have to following transition on height and width  -

```
transition: width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s
```

[Here is the example -  jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/j80yp0c1/)

for now the rectangle starting to grow from its upper left edge  , I want to change it such that it would start to grow from the center of its upper side , like the follow img  -

[image]

How to get it ?

Comment: Add `margin: 0 auto` - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j80yp0c1/1/)

Comment: You can handle this by adjusting `margin-left` property http://jsfiddle.net/j80yp0c1/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to add to your CSS

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j80yp0c1/2/)**